# How to uncheck the previous selected mat checkbox based on single check

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox, mat

I'm trying to uncheck a previous selected checkbox based on clicking one new mat checkbox

My HTML:

```
  <form [formGroup]="deleteform" (submit)="submit()">
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let test of getvalue?.food">
        <mat-checkbox [disableRipple]="true" [value]="test.id" [name]="'test.id'"
          aria-label="Value">{{test?.category[currentval]}}
        </mat-checkbox>
      </li>
      <mat-checkbox (change)="unCheckAll($event)">None of Above
      </mat-checkbox>
    </ul>
    <button>
      submit <br>
    </button>
  </form>
```

MY TS:

```
deleteform: FormGroup;

this.deleteform= this.fb.group({
     info: [
     '',
     [Validators.required],
     ],
});

unCheckAll($event) {
  this.deleteform.reset();
}
```

So far I tried this but it's not working, Any solution to uncheck previous selected checkbox based on clicking a new checkbox.

Comment: Why aren't you using a [radio button](https://material.angular.io/components/radio/overview) group for this? Checkboxes are independent, radio buttons are grouped to automatically check/uncheck each other.

Comment: can you provide the complete code of your component ?  the getValue object and submit functions ?

Comment: I need to select multiple values so I can't use radio button @DM

Answer (score 1):

If you use **Reactive Forms** it's very simple. First create your `FormGroup` like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      userCheck1: new FormControl({ value: true }),
      userCheck2: new FormControl({ value: true }),
      userCheck3: new FormControl({ value: true }),
    });
  }
  reset() {
    this.form.reset();
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML part

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="userCheck1" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="userCheck2" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="userCheck3" />
</form>
<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

If you bind the input with the `formControlName` attribute to your `FormGroup` then it works as well.

Here is a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-reactive-form-conditional-checkbox-disa-v8hjvk?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

## Update

If you wanna deselect any checkbox if you click another you can do it like this:
*HTML*

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="info" (click)="disableOthers('info')" />
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="info2" (click)="disableOthers('info2')"/>
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formControlName="info3" (click)="disableOthers('info3')"/>
</form>
<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
<input type="checkbox" (click)="reset($event)" />
```

*Code*

```
 disableOthers(controlName: string) {
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach((key) => {
      if (key !== controlName) this.form.get(key).setValue(false);
    });
  }
```

If you click any checkbox the method will called with the key of the `FormGroup` and uncheck all the other checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to Achieve this with form builder. as like I have requested in the question, would there be any solution for that ? @Flo

Comment: It’s the same with formbuilder.

Comment: But It's not working for me, besides I don't need button to uncheck the previous selected checkboxes, I need to do that based on the checkbox click which uncheck the previous selected checkboxes

Comment: Can you change the solution to form builder since I'm passing dynamic value inside it, so you can give solution based on that so that might be helpful for me

Comment: I have edited my question with form builder I do have, can you give answer based on that, so it will be helpful

Comment: Stackblitz is updated. And again: it's the same with as without FormBuilder.

Comment: No problem. If the answer is helpful you can set it to the answer of your question, too. Thx!